# Is it possible to design conditionally executed tasks in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

For example, by branch name you might want to execute different tasks (regress testing in release branches instead of massive integration tests for example).

Is there a mechanism to do that in Bamboo's UI?

Comment: You could create separate build plans and have each of them trigger on a different set of branches (see the plan branches settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is some GUI way to do this

I am triggering the same plan in different ways from a REST request by using a variable

To do this

1. define a variable in the plan configuration variables ie `myvariable`
2. in the REST request set `bamboo.variable.myvariable` to the value required ie "1" or "2"
3. in the plan stage add a task of script and use the variable as `$bamboo_myvariable` for instance

`if [ "$bamboo_myvariable" == "1" ]; then 
   # stuff to do variation 1
fi
if [ "$bamboo_myvariable" == "2" ]; then
   # suff to do variation 2
fi`

If you want to alter behaviour by branch there are variables such as "bamboo_planRepository_1_branch" which are available by default and could be used ina  similar way

Answer (score 3):

Atlassian Labs have now provided this functionality as an add-on: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219706/conditional-tasks-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview

Only available for versions 6.7.1+

**Update:**

This add-on is only supported up to Bamboo 7.0.6 and conditional tasks are a standard feature in Bamboo 7.1+

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-7-1-release-notes-1013854809.html